# browser cancels request to server on redirecting

Tags: javascript, safari

I am implementing a click tracking solution. I decided to use new Image(1, 1) to do the server request. on IE, Chrome, FF it works but on Safari the server request is canceled when redirecting. here is my code:

```
function processClick(){
    var img = new Image(1, 1);
    img.onload = img.onerror = function(){
       img.onload = null;
       img.onerror = null;

   }
    img.src = "server.ashx";
}
```

only on Safari this request is not honored. i don't care about the response, i just want to get a hit in the server. Can someone point out what happens with Safari?

I don't do an e.preventDefault() on the click handler, It can mess up context menu on FF. Or if any errors it stops browser from navigating.
Thanks

Comment: This seems like it's just a timing issue. When you redirect, any scripts on the old page stop running. Safari just happens to stop that image load sooner than the others.

Comment: I tried to do the redirect on a setinterval for 500ms and got the same situation